# watchOS app launched via Xcode is deleted from device after some time

Tags: xcode, watchos

I'm able to build and run my watchOS app (debug build) on my watch, but some time later when I'm not using the app (few minutes to few hours), it's is no longer available in the app list and I have to re-run it from Xcode. Has anyone else encountered this?

I'm using Xcode 15.0.1, watchOS 10.1, Apple Watch Series 8

Answer (score 0):

Need to enable Xcode setting "Supports Running Without iOS App Installation"